# Installation interrupted 12.04, usb method

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb

I am very new to linux operating systems, and I recently tried to download ubuntu on my girlfriends computer using a usb drive. However, when the installation process was close to being complete, my girlfriend unknowingly removed the usb from the slot, and all hell broke lose, the computer screen went black, I had left prior to the incident, so she told me she tried to reset the computer and it brought her to a page with a bunch of confusing encryptions and options, she Isn't very technologically inclined, but I am assuming this is a problem that can be fixed, although my countless hours of research has deemed inconclusive, could someone give me a little insight on how to solve this mess? it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just reinstall? Try to delete the partitions you made with the old istallation and just make a new one. I recommend the because i see you did not finish the installation process so there are no important files or configurations that need to be saved.